# Strange error with hardware picking in directx

Tags: c++, directx

i am trying to get pickigng working in directx 9 and i am having some trouble. it works fine when i am rendering my mesh in software however i do get errors when rendering with a shader. 
i can be off of a mesh but it still detects it as a hit (see image for more detail)

i am stopping animation controllers and updating frame matrices but still no joy with the picking.

http://tweetphoto.com/a7vtajzt

any help much apprechiated this has been  driving me nuts for two days now.

regards
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not to worry i found out that i was missing a clone function that i was doing in software mode but not hardware